# C# Keydown/Keyevents if no key is pressed

Tags: c#, keypress, keydown, keyevent, keyeventargs

I am programming something right now in c#, trying to "convert" a console application to a windows Forms application and I wanted to do something like the following:

```
if("keypress == nokey") 
{
    system.threading.thread.sleep ***
}
while(nokeyispressed) 
{
    system.threading...
}
```

Basically ask if no key is pressed sleep for some time and this.close();

so that if no key is pressed, do something...
I just can't get it to work.
I would be very greatful for some help..:D

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do something if no keydown event occurs for a certain amount of time?

Comment: no just like this
`if("keypress == nokey")
    {system.threading.thread.sleep ***}
`

Comment: an if-loop ? can you try to explain your question in more detail please?

Comment: keydownevent = key was pressed

Comment: system-wide or for your application only? can you tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: if you sleep when no key is pressed you can as well do this: `while(true) { /* something to keep the CPU warm */ }` ... your program will hang from this point...

Comment: Are you just trying to wait for a key event to happen in the program?

Answer (score 1):

If no key pressed, then no KeyDown event raised. So, your handler will not be called.

UPDATE (option with loop removed, because timer will make same for you as loop on different thread with sleep timeouts):

Here is sample with timer:

```
private bool _keyPressed;

private void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_keyPressed)
    {
        // do what you need
    }
}

private void KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _keyPressed = true;

    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        // process pressed key
    }

    _keyPressed = false;
}
```

UPDATE: I think good idea to verify how many time elapsed since last key down before decide if no keys were pressed

```
private DateTime _lastKeyDownTime;
private const int interval = 100;

private void LoadHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // start Threading.Timer or some other timer
 System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(DoSomethingDefault, null, 0, interval);
}   

private void DoSomethingDefault(object state)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - _lastKeyDownTime).TotalMilliseconds < interval)                            
        return;            

    // modify UI via Invoke
}

private void KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _lastKeyDownTime = DateTime.Now;

    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        // directly modify UI
    }  
}
```

Comment: sorry but depending if the loop is running in the same thread (likely the UI-thread) or not this will hang the programm and the handler will never be called - even if this will work and if you do some work in default (so the compiler will not just strip it) you will have one cpu-core on 100% ... not likely to be usefull IMHO

Comment: it's not getting better - yes the timer might be a good idea but you would neet to use KeyDown/KeyUp to set your flags - and now you have to be concernded about concurrency as well...

Comment: maybe i could set a normal timer to do the action i require,
having my key down in a loop, 
and if a key is pressed set the timer to inactive.?

Comment: Well, running loop on UI thread is definitely not good idea. If I would implement it, I'll use separate thread with Inovkes on UI thread. To make less CPU load, Thraed.Sleep will be usefull here. Anyway, I think timer is really what he needs here.

Comment: yes, thats it, i'll run a timer, if a key is pressed, the timer becomes inactive else the timer goes on and closes the program after 10 secs...

Comment: Why timer becomes inactive? Btw is it Winforms, Wpf or Console app?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky forms, because i want the program to exit if no key was pressed after `x` seconds

Comment: Then my last option exactly for your case. Set interval to X*1000. And close application in DoSomethingDefault method. Btw you need to postpone first check, so use `Timer(DoSomethingDefault, null, *interval*, interval)` instead